# Avoid a GUID refresh in OBIEE

Tags: metadata, business-intelligence, obiee

I am unable to login to Answers (/analytics) after every time I deploy the metadata repository of OBIEE using Enterprise manager, on Linux. It works after I refresh the GUIDs. Is there a way to avoid refreshing GUIDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the rpd offline before deployment, Goto Manage -> Identity->users
Check if your users are there in the rpd, if so remove them. Now deploy your rpd on your target instance. This should go fine. You wont have to reset GUIDs...
Cheers,
RamC

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

1. Stop BI Server

   opmnctl stopproc ias-component=coreapplication_obis1
2. Backup the original repository

   cp repository1.rpd repository2.rpd
3. Modify repository1.rpd on a Windows machine and copy it back to the Linux machine running OBIEE
4. Start BI Server

   opmnctl startproc ias-component=coreapplication_obis1

Answer (score -2):

## Stop Services in Linux:

1.Stop opmnctl

Navigate to /instances/instance1/bin

./opmnctl stopall

2.Stop Managed Server (bi_server1)

Navigate to /user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin

./stopManagedWebLogic.sh bi_server1

3.Stop Admin Server (weblogic)

in the same above location

./stopWebLogic.sh
4.Stop Node manger

Just kill the Node Manager process

ps -ef|grep node  –to find nodemanger pid

kill -9

Note: If Managed and Admin server not stopped properly ,you can kill same way like above

ps -ef|grep weblogic

kill -9

Start Services:

======================

1.Start Node Manager

Navigate to /wlserver_10.3/server/bin

nohup sh startNodeManager.sh &

2.Start Admin Server

Navigate to /user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin

nohup sh startWebLogic.sh -Dweblogic.management.username=weblogic -Dweblogic.management.password=weblogic123 > admin_server.log &

Tip: you can check log using tail command

tail -f admin_server.log
ctrl-z or ctrl-c to exit log window

3.Start Managed Server (bi_server1)

In the same above location

nohup sh startManagedWebLogic.sh bi_server1 http:// managed_server.log &

4. Start opmnctl

Navigate to /instances/instance1/bin

./opmnctl startall